# Writing to a json file is not in correct format

Tags: java, json, gson

I am creating a java project which writes data to an already existing json file.I am using gson libraries to write.The problem is when i write the json it written at the end of the file not inside.Here is my json before i run the program

```
{
 "trips":[
{
  "tripname":"Goa",
"members":"john"}
]
}
```

here is my java code

```
FileOutputStream os=new FileOutputStream(file,true);
BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new   OutputStreamWriter(os));
Gson gson=new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String temp=gson.toJson(trips);
bw.append(temp);
bw.close();
```

and here is my output json

```
{
 "trips":[
  {
  "tripname":"Goa",
  "members":"john"}
 ]
 }{
  "tripname": "trip1",
"members": "xyzxyz"
}
```

the newly added must be inside the trips array how can i achieve it.

Comment: You probably need to load (and parse) the file in first, then append the new trip to the existing array.

Comment: You're simply appending the new JSON to the end of the file.  You need to read in the file, modify the internal representation of the JSON, then write it back.  No "append".

Comment: (You have probably been confused by the silly array of JSON tools that Java has.  Start with a tool that simply deals with JSON as Maps and Lists.)

Comment: @HotLicks thanks i will go through and work on that.

Comment: @HotLicks could you please tell me the easiest way to serializing and deserializing json using gson.I had seen many codes indifferent form

Comment: I find the GSON interface to be overly complex and quite non-intuitive.

Comment: @HotLicks Is there any other interfaces which is easier?Could you give your suggestion

Comment: Go to json.org.  There are 20-30 different JSON APIs for Java listed at the bottom.

Comment: @HotLicks  thanks.I will see it

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are not using Gson. You need to have `Java Bean` with proper Gson annotaions and with this use Gson to serialize.

Look at this example: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples

Edit
More or less it would look like this:

```
public class Trip implements Serializable {
  private String tripName;
  private String members;

  // getters setters
}
```

Using Gson:

```
List<Trip> trips = new ArrayList<>();
// add to list

Gson gson = new Gson();    

// to json
String json = gson.toJson(trips)

// from json
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Trip>>(){}.getType();
List<Trip> trips2 = gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);
```